# Free secure bike parking at Harwich International

Tags: bicycles, england, train-stations

Where can I find free secure bicycle parking at or near Harwich International railway station, Essex, UK for about 10 days in summer 2013?

Comment: *Free* and *secure* are often mutually exclusive in urban areas, unless you use five layers of locks and take away everything of value that can be taken away (wheels, seat, ...)

Comment: It's all relative, of course, but here is one example from Cambridge: http://www.camcycle.org.uk/resources/cycleparking/grandarcade/

Comment: Can't you just take your bikes with you on the ferry to the Netherlands? That both avoids the need to leave them for 10 days, and means you have a bike with you over there!

Comment: That assumes that I'm taking the ferry to the Netherlands :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider [Warm Showers](http://www.warmshowers.org/) - it's like couchsurfing, but for cyclists.  If you find a member nearby, they may be willing to look after your bike for you for 10 days at their house, which would presumably be secure as they keep their own bike there too.